# SSO between two web app deployed on the same server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web, weblogic-10.x

I have two say(web1 and web2) web app in weblogic deployed on the same server.web2 is accessible only if user login into web1 if user tries to hit web 2 without login in tp web 1 it should redirect to web 1 login page.currently i am doing by keeping variable in servlet context. Please suggest me correct way to do this.
note:I am using security realm authenticator as well in web1.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to implement a security framework, for example, Spring http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/index.html

Comment: both the application is already build and rolled out cant change the framework.